# Получение списка сущностей в отношении @OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa

В сущности `Item`:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "shopping_cart_id")
private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
```

В сущности `ShoppingCart`:

```
@OneToMany
private List<Item> items;
```

При получении сущности `ShoppingCart` надо получить список сущностей `Item`. Как это сделать? Пробовал по разному мапить, но всякий раз список из `Item` всегда пустой?

Comment: fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Answer (score 0):

У меня примерно так:

```
class Param {
    @Id
    public Integer param_id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "param_id", referencedColumnName = "param_id")
    public List<ParamValue> values;
}

class ParamValue {
    @Id
    public Integer value_id;

    @Column
    public Integer param_id;
}
```